# How to handle Cross Origin iframe elements in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

As part of e2e scenario, I am trying to select credit card details on Payment Page of 3rd party website. Unless i make the payment my scenario will not be completed. Post Payments i also need to check the order details.

I am getting below error -
Cypress detected a cross origin error happened on page load:

> Blocked a frame with origin "https:// some url" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
> Before the page load, you were bound to the origin policy:
> https:// some url
> A cross origin error happens when your application navigates to a new URL which does not match the origin policy above.

I checked with { chromeWebSecurity: false } in cypress.json file and few other getIframe() methods but it is not working.

Is this possible to test such scenario with current cypress limitations?

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71277156/17865804).

Answer (score 0):

Cypress does not support cross domain testing. If you want to test this, copy the url as a variable and then add another test starting with:

```
cy.visit(url)
do stuff here
```